# unable to check textfield is empty or not

Tags: java, forms, awt, actionlistener

I'm beginner is java. I'm trying to check textfield is empty or not in java.  I'm using awt, awt event.I have taken  2 texfield 1 button and 1 label. When Button click it will check that both text field are not blank if both textfields are blank then it will show Error text in label else if both fields are not  blank then it will show Success text in label.
check my code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class form{
public static void main(String args[]){

//initializing components here//
Frame f= new Frame("Test");
TextField tf1= new TextField();
TextField tf2= new TextField();
Button b1= new Button("click me");
Label Toast= new Label("Default Toast");

//Setting Positions//
tf1.setBounds(30,50,100,20);
tf2.setBounds(30,100,100,20);
b1.setBounds(30,150,100,20);
Toast.setBounds(30,185,100,20);
//End  Setting Postitions//

//Start Button Listener//
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){  
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  
if(tf1.getText()==null && tf2.getText()==null){           
Toast.setText("Null field");}
else{
Toast.setText("Success");}  
}  
}); 

//End Button Listener here//

//Adding to Frame//

f.add(tf1);f.add(tf2);f.add(b1);f.add(Toast);
f.setSize(400,400);
f.setLayout(null);
f.setVisible(true);
}
}
//Adding to Frame End//
```

Comment: What is your specific error?

Comment: *I'm beginner is java....I'm using awt* - Most people would use Swing. Check out the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for Swing basics and examples. Also, you should be using layout managers, not a null layout.

Answer (score 1):

The string is empty, not null. `tf1.getText()==null` won't work in that case, you need to do

```
 tf1.getText().isEmpty()
```

To check if the String is empty.